# Google Sheets API - get multiple named ranges at once

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a quick question regarding google sheets api using java script.
Can I enter multiple ranges (e.g. named ranges) at once to keep the number of requests low?

The code I have so far:

```
const RANGE = "'GM Cheat Sheet'!";

const response = await fetch(
        `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ID}/values/${RANGE}?key=${API_KEY}`
    );
    const { values } = await response.json();
    console.log(values);
```

Any help is appreciated :)

I tried defining the range as follows:

const RANGE = ["'GM Cheat Sheet'!Range1", "'GM Cheat Sheet'!Range2"];

This did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about using "Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet"? When this method is used, the multiple ranges can be used by one API call. When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
const API_KEY = "###"; // Please set your API key.
const ID = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
const RANGE = ["Range1", "Range2"]; // This is from your question.

const ranges = RANGE.map(e => `ranges=${encodeURIComponent(e)}`).join("&");
const response = await fetch(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ID}/values:batchGet?key=${API_KEY}&${ranges}`);
const { valueRanges } = await response.json();

const obj = valueRanges.reduce((o, { values }, i) => (o[RANGE[i]] = values, o), {});
console.log(obj);
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from the ranges of `RANGE`.
- In the case of a named range, the name of the named range is a unique value in the Google Spreadsheet. So, in this case, when "Range1" and "Range2" are the named range, you can use `const RANGE = ["Range1", "Range2"];`.
- By adding `const res = valueRanges.reduce((o, { values }, i) => (o[RANGE[i]] = values, o), {});`, the returned value is as follows. By this, you can retrieve the values of the named range as `obj.Range1` and `obj["Range1"]`.

  ```
    {
      "Range1":[### values ###],
      "Range2":[### values ###]
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)

Comment: This looks very promising. Didn't habe the chance to try it out yet. Out of curiosity: does this just give me a list of the cell values or does it also link them to the named range so that I can later on easily reference the data?

Comment: @Co0n Thank you for replying. About your additional quesiton of `does this just give me a list of the cell values or does it also link them to the named range so that I can later on easily reference the data?`, when this script is run, you can see the values from the ranges in the console. The sample value of `valueRanges` is like `[{"range": "'GM Cheat Sheet'!Range1", "majorDimension": "ROWS", "values": [### values ###]},{"range": "'GM Cheat Sheet'!Range2", "majorDimension": "ROWS", "values": [### values ###]}]`. About `Didn't habe the chance to try it out yet`, I apologize for this.

Comment: @Co0n By the way, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `does this just give me a list of the cell values or does it also link them to the named range so that I can later on easily reference the data?`, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot find your expected values from `const RANGE = ["'GM Cheat Sheet'!Range1", "'GM Cheat Sheet'!Range2"];`. So, in this answer, the raw response value from Sheets API is returned. If this was not your expected value, I apologize again.

Comment: Hi, please do not apologize! I very much appreciate your help! To rephrase my question: in the example I have 2 named ranges in my spreadsheet. I would like to import the values of these named ranges as variables or objects named after the respective named range.

Comment: @Co0n  Thank you for replying. From your added information, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: @Co0n Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hey, sorry to continue with this. I just realized, that if I have hundreds of named ranges, I would need to manually enter all of them in the RANGE array. Is there a way to automatically import all named ranges as variables/arrays/objects without having to manually enter them?

Comment: @Co0n About your new question of `I just realized, that if I have hundreds of named ranges, I would need to manually enter all of them in the RANGE array. Is there a way to automatically import all named ranges as variables/arrays/objects without having to manually enter them?`, I would like to support you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249231/discussion-between-co0n-and-tanaike).